# Did Will really enter the Upside-Down?

Tags: stranger-things

After the events of the first Season, Will is shown to experience “episodes” where he seems to see or enter the Upside-Down. On the one hand, it would seem as he couldn’t enter the Upside-Down while having these episodes—apparently they have been occuring for a while, and other people have seen him having them, so they probably would have noticed if he disappeared into the Upside-Down.

On the other hand, during one particularly bad episode, he

> was possessed by the Mind Flayer,

something which would seem impossible if he were merely seeing in.

Did he enter the Upside-Down each time he had those episodes? Or only some of the time? Or not at all?

Comment: It could be that the Mind Flayer placed a "backdoor" in Will during latter's stay in Upside-Down in S1, possibly via Dart.

Comment: I took it as he was seeing it mentally not physically there.

Comment: @DCook - That was my initial presumption, but the Mind Flayer virus certainly seems like something physical that has to go through a tear.

Comment: @Adamant, indeed, and when the possession (for want of a better term) leaves Will's body, it certainly wasn't a purely mental thing, as his family seemed able to see it and it broke a window, so it definitely appeared to have a real-world, physical presence. I guess it's possible Dart left something inside Will which was physical, but required a mental trigger from the Mind Flayer (so the initial contact was mental, the later manifestation was physical, and its just a coincidence/cinematic convenience that they looked the same to the viewer).

Comment: It may not have been a coincidence that Will was standing outside on grass when the initial "possession"/infection occurred. We do know that the Mind Flayer had roots underground throughout Hawkins, and presumably they aid in the spreading of the virus.